# Custom taxonomy and query multi conditions

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query, multi-taxonomy-query

I have this query

```
$query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'location',
                         'operator' => 'IN',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $availableRegions,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'location',
                         'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $notavailableRegions,
                    )
                ));
```

and it's return this sql query

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN wp_icl_translations t
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id 
AND t.element_type IN ('bla') JOIN wp_icl_languages l
ON t.language_code=l.code
AND l.active=1
WHERE 1=1  


AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (200) 

OR wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT object_id 
FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (201,203,205,206) )
)
```

but what i really need is to return this sql

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) JOIN wp_icl_translations t
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id 
AND t.element_type IN ('bla') JOIN wp_icl_languages l
ON t.language_code=l.code
AND l.active=1
WHERE 1=1  


AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (200) 
OR wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (201,203,205,206) 

)
```

any suggestions to save my weekend :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 5 instances:
200, 201, 202, 203, 204

**NOT IN {200, 201, 202}** is equal to **IN {203, 204}** (all the other instances).

So you don't need your IN operator anymore because its results are already included from using the NOT IN operator.

In your case, this logic works assuming an article does not have multiple locations.

```
$query->set('tax_query',

        array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $notavailableRegions,
            )
        )
);
```

Comment: I have also post without any regions, i want to include them in this query

Comment: If they have no taxonomy, then you can't query them with 'tax_query' ... A solution that Wordpress itself adopts with its "Uncategorized" category for posts. You can create a "NoLocation" taxonomy yourself, and then the logic above works! Noting that in your question, nothing about posts without "locations" was mentioned.